# FTP Upload multiple files without disconnect using .NET

Tags: .net, ftp

I'm uploading multiple files using FtpWebRequest.
But for every file I'm opening and closing a connection.

How can I upload multiple files using the same connection?

Like a ftp client application, connect using username and password, change directory, upload file1, upload file2, upload file3, disconnect.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264000/downloading-files-from-multiple-directory-in-one-ftp-connection-with-ftpwebreques

Answer (score 1):

The default value of FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive is *true*. Are you explicitly setting KeepAlive to false?

Answer (score 0):

I had run into a similar issue. Transfer several related image files after corresponding DB updates are successful. I used the solution on this page 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx' to get a better performance. I too am opening and closing connection every time, except the images are loading in the background. I hope to find a better solution but this seems like a right direction.