# Downloading files from multiple directory in one FTP Connection with FTPWebRequest in .NET

Tags: .net, ftpwebrequest

Is it possible to change the Path of the FTP session once the Session is Open. The reason I want to do this is to avoid  to open the multiple FTP connection. The whole purpose is to download the files located in the FTP site in a single FTP connection. For example, in single FTP connection, I want download the contens from all the directory located in the FTP site. Currently, I have project that is failing everyday because It makes multiple connections to the FTP site to download files from different directory . For example, making more than 80 connections in 1 minutes.

What are restrictions of the FTPWebRequest in .NET

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772654/ftp-upload-multiple-files-without-disconnect-using-net

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation for [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx):

> Multiple FtpWebRequests reuse existing
>   connections, if possible.

Admittedly that does not really tell you much but if you look at the documentation for the [ConnectionGroupName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.connectiongroupname.aspx) property, it tells you that you can specify the same ConnectionGroupName for multiple requests in order to reuse the connection.

Here is more information on [managing connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y44063y.aspx) in .NET.

Alternatively, you should be able to use the WebClient class to issue multiple related FTP requests and although I can't say for sure, I would imagine that it would reuse the connection. Unlike FtpWebRequest which can only be used once, WebClient can be used to make multiple requests.